# Why does explode on null return 1 element?

Tags: php

```
var_dump(count(explode(',',[]))); // 0
var_dump(count(explode(',',''))); // 1
var_dump(count(explode(',',null))); // 1 ????
```

I was expecting 0 for the last one. Can someone tell me the reason why exploding from `null` is 1 and not 0? (PHP 5.6.16)

Comment: 1) I don't get the same results: https://3v4l.org/k6aaS 2) RTM: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php#refsect1-function.explode-returnvalues

Comment: My guess is NULL probably type juggles to the empty string.

Comment: explode expects only a string as a second parameter, and you give it some weird params. As the function name states - it "explodes" _a string_ into an array using a delimiter you provide.

Comment: @Rizier123 sorry, corrected.

Comment: `NULL` might return as `false` and because `false` or in this case `0` has a length of 1, it returns that amount.

Comment: @Tom Why is `null` `false` which is `0`... wut? That's one type conversion too many somewhere in your head...

Comment: @deceze `null` == `0` would have been shorter indeed.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`explode` takes a string as its second argument, [by specification](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). You gave it a `null`, so before the logic of `explode` runs, PHP converts the `null` into a string. Every function operates this way: if the arguments don't match the formal specification, PHP attempts to "type juggle" until they do. If PHP can juggle, the engine motors along happily, otherwise you get a weak slap on the wrist:

> PHP Warning:  explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in file.php on line 1

The way PHP juggles null to string is simple: `null := ''`. So a call with `null` and a call with `''` are semantically equivalent because of type juggling, as seen [here](https://3v4l.org/CJhKY):

```
$a = explode(',', '');
$b = explode(',', null);
var_dump($a === $b); // true

$a = count(explode(',', ''));
$b = count(explode(',', null));
var_dump($a === $b); // true
```

So now you might ask: why does PHP return a one-element array when exploding on an empty string? That is also [by specification](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php#refsect1-function.explode-returnvalues):

> If delimiter contains a value that is not contained in string ... an array containing string will be returned.

Comment: *"otherwise you get a nice fatal"* – this is PHP we're talking about, more often than not it's more like a weak slap on the wrist. ;)

Comment: @deceze Haha! Love it, I just *had* to use that description!

Answer (score 5):

As a workaround, use

```
array_filter(explode(',', $myvar));
```

Then you get an empty array and `count()` will return 0. Be aware, that it will also return an empty array, when `$myvar == ''`

Comment: if it returns an empty around then wouldn't that mean I need another check? If so, wouldnt that be less optimal than the answer above? I can see an advantage of using this way if I chain the array_filter method

Comment: @azngunit81 it depends on your requirements. If you need to distingish null and '' then it would be less optimal.